# Getting an Eclipse RCP Mac application to show splash screen

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've tried everything, spent hours on this, created rcp example projects from eclipse downloaded for mac and selected show splash and for the life of me I cannot get my splash screen to show up. I've tried the following:

1. In product definition select the plugin that contains splash.bmp in root
2. Added show splash in plugin_customization.ini
3. Tried to use the default eclipse splash.bmp to ensure my bmp file is not corrupted.

Its frustrating that the eclipse rcp wizard when selecting show splash screen does not work out of the box and really need this for my release, any help would be appreciated. I have literally searched all of google.

Comment: What sort of RCP? A pure e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi) or a 3.x compatibility mode RCP (using org.eclipse.ui.xxx plugins)?

Comment: Does it work via the command line argument `-showSplash <path-to-splash.bmp>`? Does the `.ini` file contain the line `-noSplash`? Please note, the BMP format specifies different Bit modes, but Eclipse supports only one of them.

Comment: Using Luna as target platform

Comment: i tried command line argument with showSplash like this ...
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar -mayapp  -clean -console -product com.kntrade.rct.xview.ui.wavetrade -configuration /Users/dkrebs/Desktop/WaveTrade/Contents/eclipse/configuration —showSplash Users/dkrebs/Desktop/splash.bmp

Answer (score 0):

By default, the **splash screen is made visible by the executable** even before the Java VM is started ([here is the C code for macOS that does this](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature/library/cocoa/eclipseCocoa.c#n267)).

If you bypass the executable **by calling directly Java** (`java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_...`), you have to use the command line argument **`-showSplash <path-to-splash.bmp>`** (either with an absolute path starting with `/` or a releative path relative to your current working directory). By bypassing the executable, also `<executable>.ini` is not read and all arguments must be specified on the command line instead.

**If using the executable**, the **splash screen location** is specified in the **`config.ini`** (`osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/<plugin_containing_splash.bmp>`). In `plugin_customization.ini` it can be specified whether a progress bar is displayed at a later time during startup (`org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_PROGRESS_ON_STARTUP=true`).

Make also sure the [splash screen BMP is in 24-bit format (8R, 8G, 8B)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Updating_Branding#Splash_screen). Otherwise, the splash screen will not be displayed or with the wrong colors.

Since Eclipse itself is also an RCP application, you can see how Eclipse does it and experiment with it, e. g. trying to start the Eclipse IDE via `java ...` and showing a different splash screen ([*"MONKEY SEE/MONKEY DO RULE - Always start by copying the structure of a similiar plug-in"*](https://books.google.de/books?id=Uo4SlCvSy40C&lpg=PA40&ots=Nn7NEseU6d&dq=eclipse%20%22Monkey%20see%2C%20monkey%20do%22&hl=de&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q=eclipse%20%22Monkey%20see,%20monkey%20do%22&f=false)).